# How do i get the canvas size (width and height) in a vector graphics editor like JHotDraw

Tags: java, canvas, height, awt, width

First i want to say that i am not very good at programming.

I am trying to implement a new figure in JHotDraw (a vector graphics editor, which also uses Java.awt). I want to get the width and the height of the canvas, because i will use it when setting the dimensions of the new figure.

In a class called AttributeKeys.java i found this attribute:

```
   /**
     * The width of the canvas. The value of this attribute is a Double object.
     * This is a value between 1 and Double.MAX_VALUE. If the value is null, the
     * width is dynamically adapted to the content of the drawing.
     */
    public final static AttributeKey<Double> CANVAS_WIDTH = new AttributeKey<Double>("canvasWidth", Double.class, null, true, labels);
```

And in another class called DefaultDrawing.java i found this method:

```
    public Dimension2DDouble getCanvasSize() {
        return (canvasSize == null) ? null : (Dimension2DDouble) canvasSize.clone();
    }
```

In my figure class, i try to print the CanvasSize like this:

```
    DefaultDrawing d = new DefaultDrawing();
    System.out.println(d.getCanvasSize());
```

And the output is null.

I can't figure out how to get the width and the height values of the drawing page/canvas. How can i do it?

Comment: 1) You're not going to be able to solve this without a lot more a) consulting the [Java Docs](http://javadoc.imagej.net/JHotDraw/) for the API, & b) showing a [mcve]. 2) I notice that [`DefaultDrawingView`](http://javadoc.imagej.net/JHotDraw/org/jhotdraw/draw/DefaultDrawingView.html) extends a `JComponent` which means that it is Swing based (or at least provides Swing ability). This is not surprising given that Swing supplanted AWT so long ago. ..

Comment: .. 3) You should become familiar with coding GUIs using core Java before returning to this project. You've bitten off a lot more than you can chew, or we can spoon feed.